# Ionic / Cordova: Avoiding CORS issues with $http request

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

According to [this page](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/), when I run `ionic emulate android -l` my app should be able to avoid CORS issues completely as there is no origin to speak of.

I'm trying to do a `$HTTP` GET request to a Google service (specifically downloading [this KML file](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8!2m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8) from Google Timeline).

I'm trying to get my app to behave just like my Google Chrome Extension does; I give the extension access to `Chrome.cookies` and `webrequest`, and I'm able to successfully do an AJAX request to the URL above.

However, when I do this from Angular in my ionic build I get the same CORS errors as though I'm doing it within the browser on my laptop.

Am I missing something here? How do I avoid these CORS errors for AJAX requests?

I'm just doing:

```
$http.get('https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8!2m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8').then(function(res){
    $scope.data = res.data;
}, function(err){
    $scope.data = err;
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if this  [disable cros issue in ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) is not working then try checking your server side has enabled Cros or not

Comment: The server doesn't allow CORS from browser requests and I don't have access to it - as in the question, it's a Google server. However, in a google chrome extension I've made I can AJAX the file with no issues, and I was assuming I could do the same here in Ionic as it supposedly doesn't have a stated origin...

Comment: am not clear o n your qustion actually adding this`"proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "//your url"
}]` to `ionic.config` should allow cros.

Comment: Doing a proxy pass won't work as it requires cookies from Google to authenticate the request.